# image not rendering with rest of scene, why?

Tags: rendering, objects, blender-internal-render-engine, image

I've been messing with textures and materials not actually knowing the difference and the effect it will have on my image as an object. Before it was shwoing in the render and now it's not.

I've linked my blend file here and i was hoping someone could point out my (most likely) noob mistake.

Cheers for any help!

[image]

Comment: Trying to download your Blender file but no luck - nothing happens.

Comment: I added a password to the blend file thing, thinking it was the right thing to do, I'll remove it and replace it without a password and hopefully that'll fix it.

Comment: @user33287 You mean the object not appearing in the rendering or the whole render view is not appearing?

Comment: The object only. It's an image I imported as a plane

Comment: Need to pack image into the file - right now the blend file doesn't contain the image so no way I can give you input on why it isn't rendering for you.

Comment: im sorry i don't understand what you mean by the image isn't packed into the file, does it not show when you download the blend file? Sorry i'm new to all this

Comment: It seems like that you have transperncy checked in the material tab. Unchecking will make the material appear but for somereason the texture won't appear just the diffuse color (tried this with my own textures too) .